# The rules of subsetting

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Having `df1` and `df2` as follows:

```
df1 <- read.table(text =" x y z
                          1 1 1
                          1 2 1
                          1 1 2
                          2 1 1
                          2 2 2",header=TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(text =" a b c
                          1 1 1
                          1 2 8
                          1 1 2
                          2 6 2",header=TRUE)
```

I can ask of the data a bunch of things like:

```
 df2[ df2$b == 6 | df2$c == 8 ,] #any rows where b=6 plus c=8 in df2
 #and additive conditions
 df2[ df2$b == 6 & df2$c == 8 ,] # zero rows
```

between data.frame:

```
 df1[ df1$z %in% df2$c ,] # rows in df1 where values in z are in c (allrows)
```

This gives me all rows:

```
 df1[ (df1$x %in%  df2$a) &
      (df1$y %in%  df2$b) &
      (df1$z %in%  df2$c) ,]
```

but shouldn't this give me all rows of `df1` too:

```
 df1[ df1$z %in% df2$c | df1$b == 9,]
```

What I am really hoping to do is to subset `df1` an `df2` on three column conditions,
so that I only get rows in df1 where a,b,c all equal x,y,z at the same time within a row. In real data i will have more than 3 columns but I will still want to subset on 3 additive column conditions.

So subsetting my example data `df1` on `df2` my result would be:

```
df1
   1 1 1
   1 1 2
```

Playing with syntax has confusedme more and the SO posts are all variaion of what I want that actually lead to more confusion for me.

I figured out I can do this:

```
 merge(df1,df2, by.x=c("x","y","z"),by.y=c("a","b","c"))
```

which gives me what I want, but I would like to understand why I am wrong in my `[` attempts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to your nice solution using `merge` (thanks for that, I always forget `merge`), this can be achieved in base using `?interaction` as follows. There may be other variations of this, but this is the one I am familiar with:

```
> df1[interaction(df1) %in% interaction(df2), ]
```

Now to answer your question: First, I think there's a typo (corrected) in:

```
df1[ df1$z %in% df2$c | df2$b == 9,] # second part should be df2$b == 9
```

You would get an error, because the first part evaluates to

```
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

and the second evaluates to:

```
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

You do a `|` operation on unequal lengths getting the error:

```
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

**Edit:** If you have multiple columns then you can choose the interaction as such. For example, if you want to get from `df1` the rows where the first two columns match with that of `df2`, then you could simply do:

```
> df1[interaction(df1[, 1:2]) %in% interaction(df2[, 1:2]), ]
```